# how to show last 10 uploaded images from a folder with php

Tags: php, html, image, list, directory

I am new to php. I need to list 10 last uploaded images from a folder.
now I have this code.

```
<?php
$imageDir = "uploads/";
$images = glob($imageDir.'*.jpg');
$flag=1;
foreach ($images as $image){
  echo '<div class="item' .($flag?' active image-resposive':''). '">'.PHP_EOL."\t\t";
?>
<img class="wow zoomIn image-resposive" src="<?php echo $image ?>" alt=""></div> 
<?php 
  $flag=0;
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you have any databse running where the files are saved? That probably would be much easier

Comment: no database files are save in folder named "upload"

Answer (score 0):

Use `opendir()` to loop through the directory and store all image filenames with last modified date in an array. Sort this array and pick 10 images so that you get your 10 most recent ones.

Answer (score 0):

How about this.

```
$imageDir = "Uploads/";
$images = glob($imageDir . '\*.jpg');

$latest = array();

foreach($images as $image) {

    $x = (string)filectime($image);
    // Incase you encounter duplicates
    // $x = (string)filectime($image) . $image;

    $latest[$x] = $image;
}

krsort($latest);
$latest = array_slice(array_values($latest), 0, 10);

var_dump($latest);
```